# .appendChild(tr) creates tr with no data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So am trying to create a table using firebase.
When I try and do this,

```
const td = document.createElement('td);
const tr = document.createElement('tr);

dbRefUsers.on('child_added', snap => { //dbRefUsers reference for users on firebase
    td.id = snap.key;
    td.innerText = snap.val();
    tableBodyObject.appendChild('td);
});

tableBodyObject.appendChild(tr);  // tableBodyObject is the reference for tbody
```

it shows a table row that is empty, and then shows another row with the data inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer I figured it out 
tr.appendChild(td);